# Request contains an invalid argument. while using Safe Browsing Api with Rails 7

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, safe-browsing-api

I want to build this simple project where users can check url safety

using Safe Browsing API but It doesn't work correctly even though

I've tried multiple ways but no success.

**This's my controller method below.**

```
def check_url
    if params[:link].present?
      api_key = ENV[""]
      # Set up the request parameters
      url = params[:link]
      
      formatted_url = canonicalize_url(url)
    
      threat_types = ["MALWARE", "THREAT_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED", "SOCIAL_ENGINEERING", "UNWANTED_SOFTWARE", "POTENTIALLY_HARMFUL_APPLICATION"]
      platform_types = ["ANY_PLATFORM"]
      body = {
        client: {
          clientId: api_key,
          clientVersion: "1.0.0",
        },
        threatInfo: {
          threatTypes: threat_types,
          platformTypes: platform_types,
          threatEntryTypes: %w[URL THREAT_ENTRY_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED EXECUTABLE],
          threatEntries: [
            { url: formatted_url },
          ],
        },
      }

      # Set up the request headers
      headers = {
        "Content-Type" => "application/json",
        "Authorization" => "Bearer #{"api_key"}",
      }

      # Make the request to the Safe Browsing API
      response = HTTP.post(
        "https://safebrowsing.googleapis.com/v4/threatMatches:find",
        json: body,
        headers: headers,
      )

      # Check the response
      if response.code == 200
        data = JSON.parse(response.body)
        puts JSON.pretty_generate(data)
        if data["matches"].empty?
          # render plain: "The URL is safe"å

          puts "The URL is safe"
          @url_is_safe = true
        else
          # render plain: "The URL is not safe"
          puts "The URL is not safe"
        end
      else
        # render plain: "An error occurred"
        puts "An error occurred"
      end
    else
      puts "link variable is empty"
    end
    puts "Response code: #{response.code}"
    puts "Response body: #{response.body}"

    puts "Request parameters: #{body}"
    puts "Request headers: #{headers}"
  end
```

I added a method to format :link variable, which is url in this case,

called canonicalize_url(url)

And this is the error shown in the logs

**Print out responses as you can see in the code, so I can understand the errors.**

[image]

**Please let me know if you had any questions or requests, Thanks!**

Comment: it's all in the instructions: https://developers.google.com/safe-browsing/v4/lookup-api#request-header

Comment: I already checked it but it's the same problem. Do you see any difference between the request in my code and the one shown in the instructions? because I checked it both and they are same.

Comment: your url is missing a `key` and `Authorization` header doesn't seem to be a thing.

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by "Authorization header doesn't seem to be a thing"? my bad I'm not native speaker!

Comment: remove this `"Authorization" => "Bearer #{"api_key"}",` from headers.

Comment: Awesome! It's working! Thank you Alex! I tested some links against the api but it seems to have some issues with it! Sometimes it returns empty responses like this {} for no reasons. I even tested the same links using curl command and it gave the same results as my rails app outputs.

Comment: `{}` is a normal response. it just means there were no matches, which is good.